# Filtering in an exact order Excel 2010

Tags: excel, filter

I am attempting to filter a column of data by an exact order. There are 1649 items in the column in question. I know how to do an advanced filter (much thanks to this site) but it orders it differently. Below is an example.

Need it to look like this

311
312
3122
313

When I filter it using the advanced filter, it does the following

311
312
313
3122

Is there a way to have it filter and have it do in an exact order?

Comment: Are all the items a maximum of 4 digits long?

Comment: The max is 5 but I was trying to keep the example succinct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add another column immediately after the last column and put this formula in it:

```
=A1*10^(4-INT(LOG10(A1)))
```

Then sort on this column, it will work

The original sort takes into account the size of the number but you with to sort it alphabetically (ie ignoring number size). This formula will make all the numbers the same size and therefore allow you to sort them.